# Using Generics and enums in C# to create a list of attributes

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, enums, attributes

Good morning.
I have the need to create a little helper class, using generics, however my knowledge of generics is very low.
So here is what i need.
i have defined enums in C#, to have description properties. for example

```
public enum EnumLineItemErrorCode
{
    [Description("None")]
    None = 0,
    [Description("helpful Desc")]
    MissnigA= 1,
    [Description("another desc")]
    MissingB = 2
}
```

I also have created helper functions that get he description out of the enums like

```
public static string GetEnumDescription(Enum value)
{
    FieldInfo fi = value.GetType().GetField(value.ToString());
    DescriptionAttribute[] attributes =
        (DescriptionAttribute[])fi.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DescriptionAttribute), false);
    return attributes.Length > 0 ? attributes[0].Description : value.ToString();
}
```

Now if i need the desc i can call the method like the following

```
EnumerationsHelper.GetEnumDescription(EnumLineItemErrorCode.MissnigA);
```

However when we want to do bindinds to a datasource i currently do the following for each value on the enum.

```
dropdownList.Add(new ListItem(EnumerationsHelper.GetEnumDescription(EnumLineItemErrorCode.MissnigA), EnumLineItemErrorCode.MissnigA.ToString()));
```

But this approach is inflexible as the enum grows in size and also because it does not automatically adds a value to the list if i just add it to the enum.

So my question is.

Can u create a helper method that will return me a list of Description, Value,
where description is the enum  description and the value is the enum internal value.
For example on the code that i have will be used as

```
object t EnumerationsHelper.GetDescriptionAndValuesAslist(EnumLineItemErrorCode);
```

and object t is structure of  with values <"None",None">,<"MissnigA","helpful Desc">,<"MissingB","another desc">

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I quickly wrote the following helper method for you

```
public static IDictionary<string, string> GetEnumBindings<T>()
{
    if (!typeof(Enum).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(T)))
    {
        throw new ArgumentException("The provided type is not an enum");
    }

    var result = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    var fieldNames = Enum.GetNames(typeof (T));

    foreach (var fieldName in fieldNames)
    {
        var fieldAttributes = typeof (T).GetField(fieldName)
                                       .GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DescriptionAttribute), false);

        var description = fieldAttributes.Any()
                              ? ((DescriptionAttribute) fieldAttributes.First()).Description
                              : fieldName;

        result.Add(fieldName, description);
    }

    return result;
}
```

And use case is:

```
var bindings = GetEnumBindings<EnumLineItemErrorCode>();
var listItems = bindings.Select(b => new ListItem(b.Value, b.Key));
```

After that just add listItems to your DropDownList.
Good luck!

UPD: Since description is not unique, I modified code a little bit to add field name as a key to the dictionary.

Comment: This solution provided the actual desired output, Thanks so much, the other one were good starting places, but this one was the complete package

Answer (score 1):

This will do the job.

```
private string[] GetEnumDescriptions<T>()
{
    return Enum.GetValues(typeof(T))
               .Cast<Enum>()
               .Select(GetEnumDescription)
               .ToArray();
}
```

Use case:

```
var descriptions = GetDescriptions<EnumLineItemErrorCode>();
```

Note: If T is not of type `Enum` `Enum.GetValues` method will throw exception.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for: [`Enum.GetValues`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.enum.getvalues%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)